# How to add string text and a variable in d3.js text attribute?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, text

I am trying to add a text field to a treemap I am creating in d3.js. I know in c++ you can do

```
string str = "again";
cout << "Hello World " + str << endl;
```

which would output

```
Hello World again
```

I am trying to do this is d3.js but I can seem to get it. Ive tried adding another text field but that doesn't work either.

This is what I currently have

```
cells.append("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 +10 })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 +27 })
              .style("font", "10px times")
              .text("Item count: " + function(d) {return d.data.itemCount})
              .attr("fill", "white")
```

which outputs

```
Item count: function(d) {return d.data.itemCount}
```

but I need it to output for instance,

```
Item count: 2042
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.text(function(d) { return "Item count: " + d.data.itemCount })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
cells.append("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 +10 })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 +27 })
              .style("font", "10px times")
              .text("Item count: ")
              .append()
              .text(function(d) {return d.data.itemCount})
              .attr("fill", "white")
```